# How to show transloadit assembly result on same page?

Tags: transloadit

How to show/display transloadit assembly result on same page? Do I need to change form action here

```
"form action="/uploads"
```

I've used the following code, it shows the result image for a second and then redirects to the original URL without showing the result image.

Code:

```javascript
$(function() {
$('form').transloadit({
wait: true,
triggerUploadOnFileSelection: true,
onResult: function(step, result){
if (step=='thumb'){
$("#thumbnail").html( "<img src=' " + result.url + " '/>");
}
},
params: {
auth: { key: "Auth_Key" }, 
steps: {
thumb: {
use: ":original",
robot: "/image/resize",
result: true,
width: 250,
height: 250,       
watermark_url: "https://transloadit.com/img/robots/170x170/video-encode.png",
watermark_size: "75%",
watermark_position: "center",          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set autoSubmit: false and then also provide an onSuccess() callback.